# Flattening nested list of strings into a single list of ints

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am being very dull this afternoon. How do I convert

```
['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6']
```

into

```
[1,9,3,10,5,8,8,11,2,7,4,5,2,6]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> L = ['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6']
>>> [int(y) for x in L for y in x.split(',')]
[1, 9, 3, 10, 5, 8, 8, 11, 2, 7, 4, 5, 2, 6]
```

---

This nested list comprehension works equivalently to this:

```
res = []
for x in L:
    for y in x.split(','):
        res.append(int(y))
```

As you can see, the top-down structure goes from left to right in the list comprehension

ie.

```
[int(y) 
 for x in L 
 for y in x.split(',')]
```

which unravelled now looks the same as the `for` loop.

---

Another way:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in ','.join(L).split(',')]
[1, 9, 3, 10, 5, 8, 8, 11, 2, 7, 4, 5, 2, 6]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I am not sure that I understand fully, the logic. If you have time, I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: @user1478335 I added that too :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there are several different ways to go about doing this I decided to run some (quick) tests to see which was fastest.

```
python -m timeit -s "L = ['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6']" "[int(x) for x in ''.join(L).split(',')]"
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.2 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = ['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6']" "[int(y) for x in L for y in x.split(',')]"
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.38 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = ['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6'];from itertools import chain" "[int(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(l) if x != ',']"
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.68 usec per loop
```

<s>Seems like `[int(x) for x in ''.join(L).split(',')]` takes the cake.</s>

**EDIT:** Following jamylak's suggestion I have added the following tests:

```
python -m timeit -s "L = ['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6']" "map(int, ''.join(L).split(','))"
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.79 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "L = ['1,9', '3,10', '5,8', '8,11', '2,7', '4,5', '2,6']" "list(map(int, ''.join(L).split(',')))"
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.02 usec per loop
```

So `map(int, ''.join(L).split(','))` or `list(map(int, ''.join(L).split(',')))` for python3 are the best way to go about it.

Comment: The fastest will prob be `map(int, ''.join(L).split(','))` on Py2 which is `list(map(int, ''.join(L).split(',')))` on Py 3